# Is it possible to host NextJS dynamic PWA application?What are the best practices?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-cloudfront

The challenge is Cloudfront is unable to figure out the screen size and keep pushing the desktop app, instead of PWA even when the screen size is small. URLs of both apps are the same. Everything works fine in the traditional Web server set up.

Can anyone provide insights on to how this can be achieved? The App does not have a database of its own. It consumes APIs from backend applications.

Presently screen size of the device is recognized from the web server.

We believe AWS Cloudfront has ways to recognize device size and switch serving from different cloudfront URLs. Any idea how that can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

It's not Cloudfront responsibility to render a different page version unless told to do so. As you said your web server is responsible for identifying the screen size, what you can do is ask CloudFront to pass the device type header and based on that your web server can serve a response. Check this AWS documentation on what different types of headers are available https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/adding-cloudfront-headers.html. You can use CloudFront cache policy to pass these extra headers and Cloudfront will cache the response based on these headers to ensure not all the requests are going to the origin.